# Symfony 2 add confirm message to action

Tags: php, symfony, controller, action, confirm

I am wondering if there's a way to add confirmation message before executing an Action in `Symfony2`.

I know that i can add a confirm message in `html` like this :

```
<a href = {{ my_route }} onclick="return confirm('Are you sure do you want to delete this file?')>"
```

but the problem is that my page will not be included in any `twig` file, so can i add the confirm message in my `Controller class` ?

**EDIT**

As i said in the comments my page will be used in Salesforce as a field named Details : I've already add my_url as javascript like this:

`Details= "javascript:document.onClick = window.location.href = my_url"`

and it works, but i still don't know how to add the confirmation message
to `Details field`

Comment: I know nothing about Salesforce so I don't have an answer but as a general comment ... It is a mistake for actions that make changes such as deleting a file to happen with a GET request. Your onclick code only happens if the client executes Javascript. Nothing prevents a browser accessing the route directly rather than through your link if someone knows the URL. If it's a public web site then even Google's crawler could visit and delete your files.  Anything that makes changes should be done with a POST or a more specific method but never a GET.

Comment: The best solution is to do this in the controller, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33176513/3250587

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is way to do that. The confirm message is an action that is performed client side. You can't add any action based message from PHP.

Where is your page will be included in ? if not in a Twig view

Edit:

I think this could help you : https://jsfiddle.net/5u6wepc5/

Html code

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="input" value="salesforce"/>
    <input type="button" id="button" value="delete"/>
</div
```

Javascript code

```
$("#button").click(function(e) {
    //this prevents that the form is submitted
    e.preventDefault(); 

    if(confirm('are you sure ?')) {
         alert('clicked ok');
        //do what you want here
    } else {
         alert('clicked cancel');
        //do what you want here
    }
});
```

Comment: it will be included in `Salesforce` in a `Formula` field of custom object

Comment: Any action that takes place on the UI will be handled client side. Can't you use Javascript to add controls on the field you want ?

Comment: `javascript code` can be included as link but i don't know how to add url to the `javascript code`

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean, but this is how you can include a javascript file

`<script src="path/to/your/javascript.js"></script>`

Can you be a little more explicit and give us some code sample of what you are doing ?

Comment: i already included the url in `javascript` like this:  `"javascript:document.onClick = window.location.href = 'my_url';"` but i still don't know how to add confirmation message before redirectin to `my_url`

Comment: Please edit your post and paste there your full template and javascript code

Comment: Question is edited, can you please help me with the javascript

Comment: You should export your javascript code in a javascript file. Having it inline is not a good practice.
Then you could use jQuery and add an event when you're link or button is clicked, to display the confirm message. https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: i will use a file later, but know i want to know how to add confirm message to the code of `javascript`